# Is it possible to override dependency of library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm tryingg to use some library, but I'm getting following error.

```
All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 8.4.0, 10.2.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1 less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

I think something like this should work but I still get same error.

```
compile'com.example.x:library:2.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
}
```

Is it possible to make external library use my app's dependency, or is there a solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: could you post your all dependencies libs here?

Answer (score 0):

Run a Gradle dependency report to see what your full tree of dependencies is.

Run:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies <module-name>:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Example:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to use multiple com.google.android.gms libraries should be in same version number.

now your are use in

```
one is  : 8.4.0
another one is : 10.2.1
```

must be change to same versions like

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
```

or

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1
```

**Note: 
once you have to used in com.google.android.gms:play-services then no need to use specific api(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth).
Because com.google.android.gms:play-services is contain all dependencies**

Hope this will be help you...